# Quick link in Google docs or browser to open Dolphin?

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, dolphin

I use a web-based productivity system (Habitica) for my daily routine and one thing I like is that I can have a hyperlink next to a task. So if a task is "Duolingo", I can format that text as a hyperlink to the Duolingo website that takes me right there. It just smooths the process and removes a little barrier.

So now I am wondering if there's any one- or two-step way of putting in a sort of hyperlink to open a file or folder (in Dolphin) or file on my hard drive, one that just doesn't work if I try to use it on a different computer. So if I have my yoga workout video in a folder on /home/XYZ/ABC/Multimedia/Videos/Video - Fitness/Yoga, is there any way of putting into my online productivity system a link that opens Dolphin to that folder (when I'm on my home computer)?

Thank you!